# Talking vs To talk

Tags: difference, american-english, british-english

- It was nice to talk to you.
- It was nice talking to you.

Which version is prefered in UK and US? Which is more popular whatsoever?

Comment: I feel like "infinitive vs. present participle" is one of the most common questions we get here.

Comment: @stangdon True, it does bother non-native speakers. And btw can we say **I look forward to know more**, instead of **I look forward to knowing more** while I'm aware the latter is correct.

Comment: We *look forward to* {something}.  The bare infinitive isn't a {something}. So "look forward to {know}" is ungrammatical. Whereas "It was *nice* {to {do}|to have|to be something, {doing}|having|being something}".

Answer (score 2):

It was nice to talk to you.
It was nice talking to you.

There is no preferred  version re UK and US. This is absolutely not an AmE versus BrE thing. (the use of TO + verb versus ING)

Both are used. Elsewhere on these forums, I gave a technical and linguistic description of the two meanings generated by these structures, which, to date, most English-speaking linguists have not described to any degree of intelligence.
Here is the explanation:  [ING versus TO in English usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/386451/which-expression-is-correct-ive-already-started-working-on-it-or-ive-alrea/386459#386459)

Comment: Alright, I will stay a while and wait.

Comment: I actually FOUND it: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/386451/which-expression-is-correct-ive-already-started-working-on-it-or-ive-alrea/386459#386459

Comment: I know of no better explanation, linguistically, that accounts for the difference between ING and TO in English than that. It's too bad that little of the man's work has been translated into English, notably his: Grammaire linguistique de l'anglais: A Linguistic Grammar of English.

Comment: Based on your answer there a straight **gerund** is better than a **to+verb**.

Comment: Yet, I think there should be subtle preference of one over the other in US and UK or at least it may occur among natives.

Comment: No, it is not about better or worse or UK and US. /I love to play tennis/ and /I love playing tennis/ are both used in both, there is no DIFFERENCE re the two varieties of English. But in both, the two forms have a slightly difference meaning, which native speakers wield without even realizing it. One knows when to say to play and when to say playing. And those slight differences in meaning are exactly the same thing in both, I can guarantee you that. My answer in the other forum was not about one being "better". One is not better. One is different from the other.

Comment: Okay, however, after reading Swan I personally stopped using **love to do smth** and use only **love doing smth**. Maybe because I'm not a native speaker I prefer the gerund.

Comment: I don't know who Swan is but any linguist who ***claims*** one is ***better*** than the other must not know his (or her?) own language. My goodness. Frankly, it's preposterous to even make a claim like that.

Comment: Michael Swan is great, it's just that I made a choice of my own.

Comment: Look you wanted an explanation,  you got one. He's wrong because the TO versus ING has different ***meanings*** in the English language.